# Adding a small comment section to a announcement

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This doesnt have to be fancy at all, its mainly the model im confused about.
Its a system where a tutor can post to a module an announcement. I have implemented that but a student needs to be able comment on that announcement. My application user has a isStudent field to determin users.

Announcement Model:

```
namespace CloserAgainThree.Models
{
public class Announcements
{
    public int AnnouncementsId { get; set; }
    public string AnnouncementContent { get; set; }
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }

    public virtual Module Module { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

}

Module model:

```
namespace CloserAgainThree.Models
{
 public class Module
{
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Announcements> announcement { get; set; }

}
}
```

Where could I change this section to allow a comment to be added. To the announcement model but how would I then like the comment model to the announcement?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ask this question before anything else you've done in the code, when the project was in your head or in a paper. Becasue, it is something about design of the entities. 
"*Make it up as you go along*" is not acceptable for this kind of work. Firstly, I would recommend you to take this [course](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/object-oriented-programming-fundamentals-csharp), i believe this will be very helpful in this sense.

So, i am assuming that you have three tables, Module, Announcement and Comment and you are not using any ORM framework. I guess, a module has announcements and an announcement has comments.

According to these, i would do this;

```
public class Module
{
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
}

public class Announcement
{
    public int AnnouncementId { get; set; }
    public string AnnouncementContent { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

No need to keep the module data inside the announcement or same for announcement in comment. What i need in in view layer is a model to bind and view.

```
List<Announcement> listofAnnouncement = dbContext.getAnnouncementByModuleId(int moduleId);

/* For example, showing the 3rd announcement on the screen */

Announcement announcementOnScreen = listofAnnouncement.Find(x => x.AnnouncementId == 3);

/* Get comments */

List<Comment> listOfComment = dbContext.getCommentsByAnnouncementId(AnnouncementOnScreen.AnnouncementId);

/*Then bind the comments*/
```

Hope i get it right and this helps.